# Change apache proxy server when detect error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, http-status-code-503

I have proxy server set with custom rewrite conditions (without balance manager) -  I'm set deliver server base on IP etc. all working fine like ex.:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://c1.domain.com:443/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / https://c1.domain.com:443/
```

My question is simple - if c1 will be offline or will return 503 error (when example apache on c1 is down) - how create rewrite rule to tel him to use c2.domain.com?